# Strange behaviour of Handler or what

Tags: android, handler

I have a strange behaviour of Handler in my app that communicates with Arduino. I had a lot of head pain while trying to debug the problem. I kind of solved the problem but i would like to know why is this happening???
I am sending simple JSON `{"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}` from Arduino to Android.

```
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
//          <What i added>
            String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
            outputBefore += readMessage;
            if (outputBefore.endsWith("\n")){
                Log.d(TAG, "Before Handler: " + outputBefore);
                outputBefore = "";
            }

            h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Line `h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();` sends the buffer and here all the magic begins...

```
h = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:       // if receive massage
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                outputAfter += strIncom;
                if (outputAfter.endsWith("\n")){
                    Log.d(TAG, "After Handler: " + outputAfter);
                    outputAfter = "";
                    }
                break;
        }
    };
};
```

As you can see in the output of LogCat sometimes the messages are equal. Before Handler the message is ok and i tested it 20k times and no error came up, but with the Handler something is going wrong. Even BluetoohSample uses Handler and it fails!!! What the heck is goig here?

```
09-25 12:18:18.742: D/bluetooth2(15858): Before Handler: {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}
09-25 12:18:18.742: D/bluetooth2(15858): After Handler: {"name": "Afghanistan: "AF"}
09-25 12:18:18.742: D/bluetooth2(15858): After Handler: : "AF"}
09-25 12:18:19.142: D/bluetooth2(15858): Before Handler: {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}
09-25 12:18:19.152: D/bluetooth2(15858): After Handler: {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}
09-25 12:18:19.522: D/bluetooth2(15858): Before Handler: {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}
09-25 12:18:19.522: D/bluetooth2(15858): After Handler: AAfghanistn", "code"n", "code": "AF"}
```

Comment: Why you sending message as bytes instead of sending the `outputAfter` variable? The problem might occurs while you casting the message to byte and also, this is not a good practice to read bytes and buffers...

Comment: @Pedram this kind of method is used in BT Sample app. Why it sends `h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();` and then reads as msg.obj `byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;` ? Maybe there is a problem? Converting object to byte array?

Comment: I don't really know, but there are a dozen of `optainMessage` method that overloaded which you can use to send your data. You should use the one that suits better for your work. Try to use breakpoints to investigate the problem in your code, see what's going on when you casting that object and what that object contains.

Comment: Also @Pedram, if i remove if statment `if (outputBefore.endsWith("\n")){` i will get my string in to pieces of random size(or it looks like random). Any ideas? The baud rate used by Arduino is 9600 and i use SoftwareSerial.

Comment: Anyway @Pedram i don't like this `msg.arg1` in `String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);`. I think this guy arg1 is garbage...

Comment: As I said try to debug your code with breakpoints, instead of guessing.